# GAE LocalDatastoreServiceTestConfig and Spring MVC Unit Tests

Tags: google-app-engine, spring-mvc, google-cloud-datastore, junit4

I'm developing an application with Spring MVC (3.2.2) and GAE (1.7.7) and I'm having some issues with the LocalDatastoreServiceTestConfig and my JUnit tests. I have an number of Service layer unit tests work OK when using...

```
private final LocalServiceTestHelper helper = new LocalServiceTestHelper(new LocalDatastoreServiceTestConfig());

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception
{
    helper.setUp();
}

public void tearDown() throws Exception
{
    helper.tearDown();
}
```

I've then created some tests that are designed to test the Spring MVC controllers such as the following...

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class UserController
{
@Autowired
private UserService userService;

@RequestMapping(value="/user/{userName}",method=RequestMethod.GET, produces="application/json")
public @ResponseBody User getUser(@PathVariable String userName)
{
    return this.userService.getUser(userName);
}
}
```

My tests look like the following...

```
@Test
public void testGetUser() throws Exception
{
    User user = new User();
    //create user object and save to db...

    //check that it's been created
    user = this.userService.getUser(userIdOne);
    assertNotNull(user);    
    ///other asserts...

    this.mockMvc.perform(get("/users/user/"+user.getId()).accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
    .andExpect(status().isOk())
    .andExpect(content().contentType("application/json"));
}
```

Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work as the code in the controller (getUser) method doesn't find the user which was created and retrieved prior to calling.

After some goggling I found some posts which talk about issues with local GAE datasources and multi-threading. The issue is that the data from the local data source is not available on other threads. This is fixed using a call to APIProxy.setEnvironmentForCurrentThread on all threads you are working with. I suspect that is the issue I'm facing here (i.e. the mockmvc code is creating a separate thread) however I'm not able to resolve this without making changes to the non-test code.

Has anyone come across this before or have any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure when I've done similar tests in the past that there won't be another thread in play.  However you can easily set a break-point in your controller and confirm that from the call stack.

I'd suggest doing that and also checking that and also that the userService and userName are as you expect.

One thing I have noticed in the past is that mockMvc expects the @Pathvariable name set.

```
@Pathvariable("userName") String userName
```

Another thing to check is that you're not simulating HRD through some apply percentage.  However it doesn't seem to be the case from the code you posted, and that you can in the test retrieve the user.

Comment: Thanks Mark. I've checked with the breakpoint and it looks like it is running on the same thread. I also confirmed that the the path variable (userName) is being populated correctly. My setup of the datastore is as basic as it can be so I don't think I'm doing anything with HRD. However I've also noticed that when running a local GAE dev server I get a similar issue. I have a url with 'bootstraps' the data which then appears in _ah/admin but cannot be accessed by the getUser controller method

Comment: Hmmm :) then I guess it looks quite unusual - like your userService and/or getUser method needs a bit of investigation.  If you have any more info feel free to add to qn. and I try to help :)

Comment: I have to confess coder error here. My user id has a '.' in the value. Spring was stripping this off the end of the {userName} value (as it assumes an extension) so although I was getting a value it wasn't quite the original value. I've fixed this by altering the mapped url to `\users\users\{userName}\details` which does the trick. I'll chalk this one up to experience.

Comment: :) at least you got to the bottom of it :)